# Show that the simple, symmetric random walk has no equilibrium distribution.

Tags: proof-verification, markov-chains

**Question.** Consider the simple, symmetric random walk on the integers given by the transition probabilities $$p_{ij}=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{2} & j=i-1\ \text{or}\ j=i+1,\\
0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}.$$

Show this has no equilibrium distribution.

**Attempt.** By definition, a countably infinite Markov chain has an equilbrium distribution *w* if it satisfies $$w_j=\sum_{i\in S}w_ip_{ij},\quad\sum_{i\in S}w_i=1.$$

Now, we compute the first few terms and see if we can spot a general pattern. We have $$w_0=\frac{1}{2}w_{-1}+\frac{1}{2}w_1,$$ $$w_1=\frac{1}{2}w_0+\frac{1}{2}w_2,$$ $$w_2=\frac{1}{2}w_1+\frac{1}{2}w_3,$$ or more generally $$w_n=\frac{1}{2}w_{n-1}+\frac{1}{2}w_{n+1},$$ for all $n\in S$.

This is where I get a bit stuck. First, I was thinking of solving the linear recurrence by setting $y^n:=w_n$ which gives me $$y^n=\frac{1}{2}y^{n-1}+\frac{1}{2}y^{n+1},$$ or equivalently $$1=\frac{1}{2y}+\frac{1}{2}y,$$ which reduces to $$y^2-2y+1=0\Rightarrow (y-1)(y-1)=0\Rightarrow y=1.$$ This then gives the solution $$w_n=c_1+c_2n,$$ but I fail to see what I can make of this.

Secondly, I was thinking of utilising condition, arriving to $$\frac{1}{2}\Big(...+w_{-1000}+w_{-999}+...+w_{-1}+w_0+...+w_{999}+w_{1000}+...\Big)=1,$$ which can't hold since we have an infinite sum on the left hand side. So from there, can we conclude that this has no equilibrium distribution? This seems a bit more promising; but would appreciate some verification on this nonetheless.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If there were an equilibrium distribution $\pi$, then it would satisfy the detailed balance equations
$$
p\pi_n = (1-p)\pi_{n+1}
$$
for all $n$. But $p=1-p=\frac12$, so this implies $\pi_n=\pi_{n+1}$. There can be no uniform distribution over the integers, so...

Comment: @Math1000 It takes some further observation about a Markov chain to show that it satisfies the detailed balance equations. In general, if $\pi$ satisfies them, it is stationary, but the converse does not always hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two problems with your approaches are

1. Even if there is an equilibrium distribution, it might not have the form $w_n = y^n$ for any $y$. So assuming that form and getting a contradiction wouldn't help.
2. There's no contradiction in an expression with an infinite sum having a finite value.

Here are some things you could try instead.

1. The maximum principle. Argue that there must be some state $i$ for which $w_i = \sup\{w_j : j \in \mathbb Z\}$. Then $w_i = \frac12 w_{i-1} + \frac12w_{i+1} \le \frac12 w_i + \frac12 w_i = w_i$. Equality holds, which means that $w_{i+1} = w_{i-1} = w_i$, and repeating this argument, we can show that all the $w_i$ are equal. This contradicts the fact that they add up to $1$.
2. If there were an equlibrium distribution $w$, then $\frac1{w_i}$ would be the expected return time from state $i$ back to state $i$. You can show that this expected return time is infinite in a number of ways, getting a contradiction.
3. Argue that the detailed balance equations $p_{i,i+1}w_i = p_{i+1,i} w_{i+1}$ must hold, as suggested in [Math1000](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/38584/math1000)'s comment above. (Maybe look at the number of transitions into and out of the set $\{i+1,i+2,i+3,\dots\}$.) Here, it implies $w_i = w_{i+1}$, which we've already seen is a contradiction.

In general, there's probably a lot of ways to prove that if there is an equilibrium distribution $w$, then all the $w_i$ are equal. If you do that, then a contradiction is not far off, since an infinite sum of equal values is either $\infty$ (if they're nonzero) or $0$ (otherwise), never $1$.

Comment: Do forgive my naivety but could you elaborate a bit on why approach 2 fails? I know there are some infinite sums which converge, but in this case it was the sum of all integers which is a divergent sum right? So surely it shouldn't be possible to get that to equal a finite number? Also thank you for the alternative approach 2; that was the only one I'm somewhat familiar with and got me my desired contradiction.

Comment: It's not the sum of all the integers; rather, it's the sum of $w_{n}$ over all integers $n$. This can have a convergent sum in a number of ways. For example, if $w_n = 2^{|n|}$ (note the absolute value), then it's a geometric series that sums to $3$.

Comment: Whoops, that should have been $w_n = 2^{-|n|}$.

Comment: hi Misha, thank you for the answer. I was reading it and you mentionned that $w_n$ is not always equal to $y^n$, which I disagree. The difference equations have unique solutions there... what other solutions are you thinking about ? BTW sorry to dig out an answer like that. However, it is such a general (difference equations ) subject that I don't think you need to remember exactly the topic of the exercice. Best, Marine.

Comment: @MarineGalantin It's not that I'm claiming that there are other solutions. But if you're trying to prove that there are no solutions then you need to do one of two things: (1) arrive at a contradiction *without* assuming that the solution has this form, or (2) prove that the solution must have this form, and only *then* prove that there are no solutions of this form, either. Just proving that there are no solutions of this form is not enough.

Comment: (Looking back, it looks like the person asking the question was trying to invoke the result that a linear recurrence has solutions of the form $w_n = C_1 \alpha_1^n + \dots + C_n \alpha_n^n$, if the characteristic equation has distinct roots $\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n$. If so, then using this and getting a contradiction would be fine.)